# OpenCV heap corruption on Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have a simple code written in Visual Studio 2010 with openCV 2.4.10 which extracts some features from some input file.

```
Mat extractSIFT(Mat img)
{
    cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector;
    cv::Ptr<cv::Feature2D> descriptorExtractor;

    detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("Dense");
    descriptorExtractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");

    detector->set("initXyStep",GRID_SPACING);

    vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect(img,keypoints);

    Mat o;
    //Mat o(keypoints.size(),128,CV_8U);
    descriptorExtractor->compute(img,keypoints,o);

    return o;
}
```

Although this code works fine in debug mode(albeit slow), it gives this error:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Prototype.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   Prototype.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Prototype.exe has
>   focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

Upon further investigation, I found that the output variable o cannot be seen in release mode(hover over), but can print values on simple console dump.

In disassembler:

```
   848:     //Mat o(keypoints.size(),128,CV_8U);
   849:     descriptorExtractor->compute(img,keypoints,o);
   850: 
   851:     return o;
013F6FCF 56                   push        esi  
013F6FD0 8D 55 C0             lea         edx,[keypoints]  
013F6FD3 52                   push        edx  
013F6FD4 8D 45 0C             lea         eax,[img]  
013F6FD7 50                   push        eax  
013F6FD8 8B CF                mov         ecx,edi  
013F6FDA C7 45 F0 01 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],1  
013F6FE1 E8 42 35 02 00       call        cv::Feature2D::compute (141A528h)  
013F6FE6 8B 45 C0             mov         eax,dword ptr [keypoints]  
013F6FE9 3B C3                cmp         eax,ebx  
013F6FEB 74 09                je          extractSIFT4+306h (13F6FF6h)  
013F6FED 50                   push        eax  
**013F6FEE E8 EC 5C 02 00       call        operator delete (141CCDFh)**  
013F6FF3 83 C4 04             add         esp,4
```

The error occurs in line with **asterisks**. I tried several project properties (/Md, MT, incremental build,...) recompiled openCV, checked platform version(v100) but no avail.

Comment: which libraries did you kink against?

Comment: Kink? What is a kink? This part of the code only uses opencv and dirent for folder listing

Comment: yes link. sorry typo. are you compiling in release mode and linking opencv debug libraries?

Comment: checked that thrice, all libraries are 2410(not d in it)

Comment: @AutomaticHourglass can you post your compiler and linker commands? Properties->C/C++->CommandLine and ->Linker->CommandLine

Comment: and can you add the same code snippet to a clean VS project including a simple call of that function and provide that main function + input image?

Comment: Post an image on which you are testing this code and show us the value of GRID_SPACING

Comment: compiler commands: /I"D:\opencv\build\include" /I"C:\Dropbox\Work\VisionFetchCode\Toolboxes\vlfeat-0.9.19" /I"C:\Dropbox\Work\VisionFetchCode\Toolboxes\elm_linear\Eigen3" /Zi /nologo /W1 /WX- /O2 /Oy- /Gm /EHsc /MT /GS- /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\Prototype.pch" /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue

Comment: link commands: http://pastebin.com/MFYbCrZR

Comment: new clean test application(which works on release mode): http://pastebin.com/2TXr0mDv

Comment: On the original program, I'm using only the code snippet I have given above which fails on release mode, but a new application works on release mode.

Comment: maybe you've broken some project settings during testing? So your question isn't answered, but you can work (from your clean project) or do you have to use the fix the old project?

Comment: @Micka The thing is, I had made a DLL of this functionality and it worked without a problem until some recent time, that DLL consisted of only required functions and can be considered a 'clean' build from scracth. 1 month ago, both prototype(this program) and DLL stopped working. Maybe I have broken some project settings but both of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For heap corruptions of any sort, Microsoft Application Verifier (freeware) is invaluable. You will need to configure it with Basics\Heaps check, I suggest to disable all other checks for the first time. After saving the settings, you will need to restart you program. It will crash exactly at the point of corruption.

For example: consider you alloc 100 bytes on heap and then try to write 101 bytes. In Debug builds, C++ CRT will add some extra padding before and after the block, which will prevent and detect small heap corruption. In Release builds, there's no padding and heap gets corrupted, which you usually learn too late, at the moment of some other heap operation. With Application Verifier, your program will crash into debugger exactly when it writes 101-st byte. When it happens, you can see some extra details in your Visual Studio's Output window.

(NB: I always keep Application Verifier with Basics\Heaps enabled for the programs I develop)

In this specific case, it's possible you will see that vector's destructor causes the crash. That will mean no heap corruption occurred, but the program is trying to delete a non-existing heap block. This will most likely be due to linking OpenCV compiled with different compiler or different Debug/Release settings. the structure of `vector` class and allocated block paddings differ between compilers and Debug/Release.

**Update:**
Now that we know different CRT is the case, here's an extended explanation.

- vector is allocated in OpenCV and freed in your program.
- if you have different versions of CRT (compiler, debug/release)

  - allocating and freeing logic can be completely different
  - your program will most likely crash.
- if you have same version of CRT

  - CRT (C Runtime Library) handles memory allocation through Windows heap.
  - Every heap has its own handle.
  - CRT (until VS2012 or smth like that) will create its own heap for allocations.
  - If you have two different CRTs, then trying to free a block allocated by other CRT will use wrong heap handle, which will either crash or leak memory
  - I guess, you had your program use CRT in static library, while OpenCV had CRT in DLL.
  - Having CRT statically linked means having a private CRT embedded.
  - Hence, you had two CRTs: one in your program, one in DLL used by OpenCV.
  - Now that you changed your program to use CRT in DLL, they both use the same DLL, which is only loaded once per process, hence you only have on CRT now.

Comment: =======================================  
VERIFIER STOP 00000006: pid 0x254C: Corrupted heap pointer or using wrong heap.  
 087D1000 : Heap handle used in the call.  
 087025B8 : Heap block involved in the operation.  
 00000A48 : Size of the heap block.  
 07DE1000 : Heap where block was originally allocated.  
=======================================  
This verifier stop is not continuable. Process will be terminated 
when you use the `go' debugger command.

Comment: This is the output I get from the application verifier, I couldn't find any useful information about it on the internet also. Any ideas?

Comment: As you can see, heap is not corrupted, but instead a wrong pointer is deleted. Check Call Stack at the moment of this new crash. I believe it's in vector's destructor, and I have already described the cause for this: you're linking OpenCV compiled with different compiler or Debug/Release settings.

Comment: You can check additional help, opening it from Application Verifier: Help | Help | Index | 0006. It says, the problem in that crash is that wrong heap handle is used. The correct heap handle is 07DE1000, but your program used 087D1000 to delete the block. This is because OpenCV allocates your vector in ::detect(), and then your code deletes it. OpenCV has its own CRT with its own heap handle. The usual workaround for this is to have precisely the same CRT in your program and linked DLLs.

Comment: You were right, in a way. I had changed the project settings and that was causing the problem, Code generation was using Multi Threaded (/MT) and project started to work when I used Multi threaded DLL(/MD) and it worked. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem mixing a debug executable with a release DLL. They likely use different heaps and/or allocators. This code is probably what's blowing up:

```
Mat o;
descriptorExtractor->compute(img,keypoints,o); // fills 'o' by reference, allocation happens in release library
return o;
// function exists, freeing 'o', free happens in debug binary
```

Check to see if OpenCV has a debug version of the DLL, and if so change your MSVC project settings to use it.

Or, you can "fix" this by adding a deliberate leak:

```
Mat* o = new Mat();
descriptorExtractor->compute(img,keypoints,*o);
return *o;
// HACK! function exists, leaking o... but so what?
```

Comment: Dll issue, checked that thrice, all libraries are 2410(not d in it). I tried using pointers for o, but same mistake happens(heap corruption). Does openCV have any other dll's to be included/linked in projects(I only link .lib files without d in their names)